Как плавно сменить цвет LinearGradientBrush?
столкнулся с проблемой плавного изменения цвета у градиента, фона кнопки (картинка ниже)

Вот код этой страницы (обрезан до проблемной точки):
<StackLayout   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <ImageButton x:Name="toChat" HeightRequest="128" WidthRequest="128"   Source="tochatbtn.png" Aspect="Fill" CornerRadius="50"  >
        <ImageButton.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop  x:Name="color1" Color="#4d2d64" Offset="0.33"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop x:Name="color2" Color="#4f3c75" Offset="0.45"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop x:Name="color3" Color="#5770b0" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
           
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ImageButton.Background>
    </ImageButton>
   
   
</StackLayout>

Как бы мне при нажатии на клавишу плавно менять цвет всех цветов в градиенте?
Я пробовал CommunityToolkit.Maui.Extensions - думал, что там есть плавная смена цвета на этот счёт, но нет (Там есть метод BackgroundColorTo).
Ощущение, будто ответ где-то передо мной, но я его упрямо не вижу. Кто-нибудь знает, как решить мою проблему?
Спасибо.

Для того чтобы что-либо плавно менять, есть анимации.

Знаете ли Вы анимации цвета, можно поподробнее?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/extensions/color-animation-extensions

К GradientStop нельзя применить данную библиотеку. Не поддерживаются методы

Ну посмотрите исходники, они отерытые, напишите своё по образу и подобию. Если надо в xaml, расширение разметки тоже не сложно сотворить. И вообще цвет можно прибиндить к свойству, и его анимировать, градиентстопы то зачем трогать?
